# Extract elements from a numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, extract

I have this array:

```
rel=np.array([1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0])
```

and

```
eta=np.array([2,3,10,16,4,3])
```

where eta is composed of elements that correspond to 0-elements in rel. In other words, eta[0]=2 is related to rel[1]=0, eta[1]=3 is related to rel[2]=0, eta[2]=10 corresponds to rel[5]=0, and so on.

From rel I randomly extract some elements, for example

```
rel_extract=np.array([1,0,0,1,0])
```

where the null elements are at 1st, 2nd and 4th indexes.

How can I create an array named eta_extract using the values in eta considering that eta_extract is made with the same rule of eta? I guess that eta_extract should be

```
eta_extract=array([10,16,3])
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you clarify the relationship between `eta` and `rel`? The explanation isn't quite clear.

Comment: I only have rel and eta. I only know that eta has the same size of the number of zeros in rel. Since rel contains 6 zeros, eta has size 6. I don't know where the eta elements come from...

Comment: Do you control how `rel_extract` is made?

Comment: rel_extract is totally random. In this example I extracted from 0,5,7,8,10 indexes

Comment: Yes it is random, but are you the one who make this random array, or does someone generate one for you?

Comment: I'm the one who makes this random array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary array of zeros that's the length of `rel`. Then get the indices of `rel` that are zero. Then map those indices in the temp array to values of `rel`. Finally, generate some random indices of `rel`, and get the associate values of `eta` at those indices where the values of `rel` are zero.

```
# An array of zeros of length rel
tmp = np.zeros(rel.shape[0]) 
# Indices of rel that are zero
zero_rel_loc = np.where(rel == 0)
# Map the value from rel to tmp 
tmp[zero_rel_loc] = eta

# Generate a subset of size 5 of indices/values from rel
i = np.arange(rel.shape[0])
rand_ind = np.random.choice(i, 5, replace=False)
rand_eta_val = tmp[rand_ind]

# Remove the extra zeros
result = rand_eta_val[np.where(rand_eta_val != 0)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you have solved a little problem for me